# Log4cxx and Log4net  should not create log file until there is something to log

Tags: logging, log4net, log4cxx

Well

> I do not want log4cxx-Log4net create a file until there is something
>   to log.

Is It possible ? If yes, How can i do it?

Comment: have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533403/log4net-how-to-disable-creation-of-empty-log-file-on-app-start